# How to enable desktop notifications for Gmail

Tags: gmail, notifications

I'm using Gmail. I'd like to receive desktop notification for every new email.

How can I receive these notifications?

Comment: "Desktop" notification term is not used for Android/iOS applications. Inbox by Gmail is a Android/iOS application and not a desktop or direct Web Application. Maybe you should correct that part of your question.

Comment: @vasilis: Inbox by Gmail is accessible from the Web. But, yes, this question was mistagged.

Comment: @AlE. thank you for the notice. Now I can see it too, I was staring at the introduction at www.google.com/inbox about its Android/iOS App version without noticing the "Go to Inbox" button at upper-right corner. I just enabled it for my Google Apps for Work too. I apologize from Sally and Darko as well for my previous misunderstanding.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to turn Desktop Notifications on for new emails from your Gmail Settings.

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?hl=en :

> ### Turn desktop notifications on or off
>
> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. In the top-right corner, click the gear icon Settings.
> 3. Select Settings.
> 4. Scroll down to the Desktop Notifications section (stay in the "General" tab).
> 5. Choose one of the options:
>
>    - New mail notifications on: If you use inbox categories, you’ll only be notified about messages in Primary.
>    - Important mail notifications on: You’ll be notified about every incoming messages marked as important. Learn more about importance
>        ranking.
>    - Mail notifications off
> 6. Click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have a question. does this work only when web tab is opened with gmail or even when it is closed?